# PHP Radio button grab two values

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, radio-button

So the below code grabs the server_id from the row that the user selects. However, I am wondering if it is possible to grab both the server_id and server_name from the row without the user having to do anymore than he already does (select a radio button and push submit). Thanks for any help.

```
<form method="post" name="server_information" id="server_information" action="test.php">
<label>Server Information</label><br><br>
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Selection</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Date Created</th>
        <th>Server Name</th>
        <th>Server Id</th>
        <th>Public DNS</th>
        <th>Server Status</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="server" value="<?php echo $row['serverId']; ?>" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['userName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['dateCreated']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['serverName']; ?>"</td>
        <td><?php echo $row['serverId']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['publicDNS'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['serverStatus']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
<br>
<?php endif; ?>

<input type="submit" name="server_stop" value="Stop Server"/>
<input type="submit" name="server_terminate" value="Terminate Server"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a pipe `|` or any other character to concatenate both in the radio value, then explode your $_POST['server'] on pipe, you'll get id in index 0 and name in index 1.

```
<td><input type="radio" name="server" value="<?php echo $row['serverId'].'|'.$row['serverName']; ?>" /></td>
```

Another solution would be to add a hidden input and name it with the server id like this:

```
<td>
<input type="radio" name="server" value="<?php echo $row['serverId']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="name_<?php echo $row['serverId'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['serverName'];?>" />
</td>
```

then in PHP

```
  $server_id=(int)$_POST['server'];
  $server_name=$_POST['name_'.$server_id];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just concatenate the two values with a comma (or other delimiter that won't appear in the values):

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="server" 
               value="<?php echo $row['serverId'] . ',' . $row['serverName']; ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['userName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['dateCreated']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['serverName']; ?>"</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['serverId']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['publicDNS'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['serverStatus']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Then when you process the form use [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/explode) to separate the results:

```
$server_info = explode(",", $_POST["server"]); // server_info is an array
$server_selection = $server_info[0];
$server_name      = $server_info[1];
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. However, I have never used explode before. I assign the server_id to a variable in the process script "server_selection=$_POST['server']" If you can offer advice on how to do that with explode, so that I have two variables. One for id and one for name, I would be very greatful

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array:

```
name="server[$row['serverId']]" value="$row['serverName']"
```

Then get it with:

```
list($id, $name) = $_POST['server'];
```